# Regex To Match Pattern Unless It Ends With A Specific String

Tags: php, regex

I'm having a little trouble coming up with a regex for my particular situation. This is what I have.

```
"#<call:(\d+)>(?:(?!\/MM).)+?(\s+)?(?=\<)#ims"
```

I need to match the following example.

```
<call:5>anything <
```

But I don't want to match this...

```
<call:5>anything/mm <
```

That's working ok, but the problem is that it won't match this...

```
<call:5>anything/mmm <
```

I need the regex to match `anything` provided `anything` does not end with `/mm`. I know it's going to be something small I'm overlooking, but could you point out what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Looking at the regex, I am not really sure what the significance of the `/mm` part of the examples is - so you basically want to match anything except `/mm`? Should e.g. `/mmx` be matched as well? What about `/mm x` with a space there? What about multiple `/`?

Comment: and to add to that, is the `space` and `<` character important here?

Comment: Your last string _'<call:5>anything/mmm <'_ ... is that supposed to be matched as well, or not?

Comment: The `<` is the next delimiter and represents the end of what I want to match. In fact, I need to stop matching at the character before the `<`, which may or may not be a `space`, hence the `(\s+)?(?=\<)`. `anything` must be invalid if it ends with `/mm`.

Comment: Yes, `/mmm` should match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one can assume that the `call` tag contents to be matched will not contain

- spaces after an (allowed?) `/mm` string or
- `<` characters (except at the end),

the following seems to work:

```
<call:(\d+)>(?:(?!\/mm[\s<]).)+?(\s+)?(?=\<)
```

**EDIT:**

I think the corner cases can be solved as well, try this instead:

```
<call:(\d+)>(?:(?!\/mm\s*?<).)+?(\s+)?(?=\<)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you FriendFX. Yes, those conditions would never happen, so your regex works. I knew it would be something simple. Cheers!

Comment: Re: EDIT - Yes, that works too, and so does `<call:(\d+)>(?:(?!\/mm\s?<).)+?(\s+)?(?=\<)`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Is what you're trying to say is if the match ends with `/mm <` then it is invalid?

```
if (preg_match('%<call:(\d+)>(?!.*/mm <\z)(.*)%sim', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

if all line end in either /m or /mmm and you want "anything" you can add this `'%<call:(\d+)>(?!.*/mm <\z)(.*)(?:/m+ <)%sim'`

Comment: Yes, if the match ends with `/mm` it is invalid.

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately, Scuzzy, even with escaping the `/`.